# Can I reuse Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have created a new Azure Logic App to alert a Teams channel whenever a Sev3 log message is written to the Azure Monitor traces database. I have parameterized all the information that can change between my Dev and Prod environments. The code itself is exactly the same.

Is there some way I can reuse the Logic App, and just have it called with different parameters based on which environment, Prod or Dev, that it is running in?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a Logic App that does all the processing, with the trigger being an HTTP request. I then created the Prod and Dev Logic apps with a trigger of Recurrence, and passed in the parameters in the request. It's working fine, and I didn't need to duplicate code.